# Free 3d modeling software for mechanical designs

Tags: 3d, graphic-design

I want to create a 3d model of a solenoid, looking something like this:

[image]

I will have to learn 3d modeling from nothing so I'm looking for a software that potentialy is directed for this kind of technical models. Some software I considered are blender and unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender isn't a program well suited to engineering type creation. I'm unfamiliar with Unity, but I suspect the same applies.

For engineering applications, you'd want a CAD type of program. Fusion 360 is one such package, free for hobbyists. Another is OnShape, a web-based program. Both programs work well for highly technical model creation. As is common with popular software, you'll find numerous tutorials on the YouTube to aid in your learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/). It should be suffcient to learn and model with.